# Design Pattern to unify similar generated classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a project where I work with generated classes for some web interfaces. Some of these classes are (almost) identical and most of the functionality I need them for only use the identical parts. Currently that functionality is implemented for each class separately. I want to refactor it in a way that I only have to implement the functionality once, independent of the used classes.

```java
package a;
public class Domain{
  //some attributes
  public String getName(){//impl};
  public String getType(){//impl};
  public Boolean getDnsSec(){//impl};
  //some setters
}
```

```java
package b;
public class Domain{
  //some attributes
  public String getName(){//impl};
  public String getType(){//impl};
  public Boolean getIsSecured(){//impl};
  public String getLastEditor(){//impl};
  //some setters
}
```

```java
package c;
public class Domain{
  //some attributes
  public String getName(){//impl};
  public String getType(){//impl};
  public Boolean getDnsSec(){//impl};
  //some setters
}
```

My current idea is to use some kind of adapter pattern but I'm not sure if it's the right approach and if I'm doing it the correct way. The implementation would look something like this:

```java
public abstract class DomainAdapter <Domain>{
  private Domain domain;
  public DomainAdapter(Domain domain){
    this.domain = domain;
  }
  public abstract String getName();
  public abstract String getType();
  public abstract Boolean getDnsSec();
  public Domain getDomain(){
    return this.domain;
  }
}
```

```java
public DomainAAdapter extends DomainAdapter<a.Domain>{
  public DomainGkAdapter(a.Domain domain) {
    super(domain);
  }
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return getDomain().getName();
  }
  @Override
  public String getType(){
    return getDomain().getType();
  };
  @Override
  public Boolean getDnsSec(){
    return getDomain().getDnsSec();
  };
}
```

I'm wondering if this a good approach, if there is something better I could do or if it's maybe just wrong what I'm trying to do here. Thanks for the help and feedback in advance.

For clarification: I can not alter the Domain classes in package a, b, and c in any way. I think currently they are rebuilt from WSDL every time I build the project again and definitely need to be rebuilt if the corresponding WSDL gets updated. I do want a single point of access for these classes when I use them in my project though.

Instead of having three methods working with `a.Domain`, `b.Domain` or `c.Domain` as parameter, I want to have one function that works with a generalized domain parameter. Classic inheritance isn't possible since I cannot add a superclass that `a.Domain`, `b.Domain` and `c.Domain` inherit from.

Example:

```java
//without adapter
public class DomainUser{
  public void useDomain(a.Domain domain){
    doSomething(domain.getName());
  }
  public void useDomain(b.Domain domain){
    doSomething(domain.getName());
  }
  public void useDomain(c.Domain domain){
    doSomething(domain.getName());
  }
}
```

```java
//with adapter
public class DomainUser{
  public void useDomain(DomainAdapter domain){
    doSomething(domain.getName());
  }
}
```

To make things simpler you can assume that a.Domain, b.Domain and c.Domain are from different libraries I import and that I have no influence over.

Comment: can you not use inheritance?

Comment: Can you elaborate what problem this adapter approach should solve for you? Can you have the Domain classes inherit from a common interface?

Comment: The initial domain classes are generated from WSDL and cannot be altered. So simply adding a superclass or common interface doesn't work.

Comment: If you cannot generate your adapter-classes you gain nothing by generating the classes from WSDL instead of writing them by hand.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I would have to update them by hand if changes to the WSDL would break something yes. If changes to the WSDL change something I do not use then no update to the adapter classes is needed though. If I didn't use the adapter classes then I would have to adjust any code that works with the generated classes as well. Like this most changed should be restricted to the adapter class.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I added an example where the adapter or some other solution would be an advantage over what I have to do right now without the adapter.

Comment: I have seen a similar solution in spring-social-core and implementations: spring-social-facebook, spring-social-google and spring-social-twitter. If that helps. The source code is on GitHub

Comment: @Laiv I assume facebook, google and twitter offer a certain API that is similar so spring-social-core added an adapter for it that gets implemented by each of these projects? Looking at the projects it's rather difficult to find which part you mean though. If you can link on of the adapter interfaces and of its implementations that would be great.

Comment: Generally speaking, you either generate classes or write them by hand; you don't do both.  You would therefore not modify a generated class; you would simply re-generate it.  Given that this is *generated* code, I don't see any need to unify these classes.  If you choose to go the non-generated route, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have several similar classes. In this case they are generated but they might as well be from a library. I want to access objects from these classes in different places. If I want to access each of these classes in a similar fassion. If it's three classes like in my example then I would have to write three ways to do so everytime I need access. With the adapter classes I would implement this once in each adapter while the classes where I want to use the access only need to know the abstract adapter.

Comment: Your examples only show two common methods.  Inheritance is the way forward, unless it isn't.  Personally, I wouldn't bother for two common methods.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the examples I chose are there to demonstrate my problem. My guess is using an adapter or something similar will save me several hundred lines of code (due to less code duplicates) while having a single point per generated class that I have to maintain.

Comment: It's generated code.  Why are you counting lines?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Only the classes `a.Domain`, `b.Domain`, and `c.Domain` are generated. The adapters that I want to add and the places where I want to use the adapter instead of the generated classes aren't generated.

Comment: @sbke yes, basically all three Social Network have in common: OAuth (different versions) service and several web APIs. The spring-social-core implements the Adapter (See Api, ApiBinding, ApiAdapter). The implementations implement API (Facebook, Google or Twitter), adapter (`GoogleAdapter implements ApiAdapter<Google>`) and other common interfaces from spring-social-core. The thing is that the spring-social project used your approach to make different Social Network APIs work under the same interface "spring-social".

Comment: @Laiv Thank you this helps a lot.